# How eliminate duplicate objects from array of objects in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I am having two arrays coming from web service, I need to find out whether the Array2 has the same objects as Array1. 
So, For this I am using below code:

```
var arr1 = [CustomObject]()
var arr2 = [CustomObject]()
var arr3 = [CustomObject]()
var arr4 = [CustomObject]()


self.arr3 = self.arr1 + self.arr2  //concatenate two arrays 
self.arr4 =  Array(Set(arr3))   // find out uniq values

//  below is the extension

extension Array where Element : Hashable {
var unique: [Element] {
    var uniqueValues: [Element] = []
    forEach { item in
        if !uniqueValues.contains(item) {
            uniqueValues += [item]
         }
       }
      return uniqueValues
    }
 }
```

But it is showing error on above line "Array(Set(arr3))"
Error Is :- To add  value to Set

Comment: What error? Is `CustomObject` `Hashable`?

Comment: Error is regarding hash values

Comment: My customObject has a name, Id, Summary... etc.  I need to identify objects with similar IDs

Comment: It'd be more helpful if you included the error message in your question

Comment: the error is that I need to provide hashable value or something, I am not aware of this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look about "Hashable + Swift", look how to do it. In a few words, you have to help the `(NS)Set` to understand how to define unicity. `(NS)Set` use hashable protocol do to so. So add "Hashable compability" to your class `CustomObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var arr1 = ["A","B","C"]
var arr2 = ["A","B","C"]

if Set(arr1).symmetricDifference(arr2).isEmpty {
    print("The Arrays Match")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Overview:

- In order for the set to store custom class / struct, the custom class / struct needs to to conform to `Hashable` `protocol` and indirectly `Equatable` `protocol`.
- Given below is an example using a `struct`, you can use a class as well.

### Code:

```
struct CustomObject : Hashable{
    
    var something : Int //It is just an example, this could be any type, but some how you should find a way to compute the hash value.

    //MARK: Hashable
    var hashValue: Int {
        
        return something
    }
}

//MARK: CustomObject - Equatable
func ==(lhs: CustomObject, rhs: CustomObject) -> Bool {

    return lhs.something == rhs.something
}
```

Comment: I have used the above, but how to specify it in " self.arr4 =  Array(Set(arr3)) "

Comment: `self.arr4 =  Array(Set(arr3))` should work just by making `CustomObject` `Hashable`